# Accessing Windows Mobile Device from Command line or C# Winform

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a device attached to my PC. Win10 loaded in drivers for it. In Windows explorer I can see the device as it comes up as WindowsCE. I can open that and navigate through its file system. What I would like to do is write a c# winform app to transfer files to it. Unfortunately I cannot find it via c# as it is not a disk and it is not in c:\users. I also tried using from command line "wmic logicaldisk get deviceid" but it is not a disk so does not show.

I find that this device is located "on UMBus Enumerator", maybe that helps us?

Any ideas how I get hold of it in c# winforms?

Comment: I think you can't. You see your device as a folder because an application (probably drivers themselves) installed an extension on Windows Explorer and this application is totally responsible for the visual part and the file transfer.

Comment: @mar: If the Shell can access the device then so can you. You could try using [WinUSB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device) or a higher-level API.

Comment: @IInspectable: Shell can't access drive, Windows Explorer can by calling the app responsible for the device. Windows Explorer doens't see a drive, but a black box that must be cotinuosly queried for items to show or actions to perform

Comment: @mar: Explorer *is* the Shell. If an item shows up in Explorer, it's usually implemented as a [Shell Namespace Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works). The Shell API allows clients to enumerate items, and provide access to them, including items implemented as extensions. Explorer doesn't *"call the app"*, nor does it poll for changes. What you seem to refer to as *"the app"* is a COM server registered with the system.

Comment: @IInspectable: I was exactly referring to _Shell Namespace Extension_, but I kept it simple. What I meant is user can't access directly the device as if it were a drive, because it's not. Accessing it using shell APIs is not exacly comfortable nor straightforward.

Comment: @mar: Opinions may differ, but seriously, accessing COM from C# is about as comfortable and straight forward as it ever gets. Also, you *can* iterate over the entries in the virtual folder as if it were a file system. So indeed you can do what the OP asked to do using just the Shell API.

Comment: I understand your point and believe me I'm used to apis in general. But they're not as simple as Directory.GetFiles :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments much appreciated, I have learnt a bit more here. I guess I need to rethink my issue and perhaps try from a different direction. I am now thinking on creating an App I can put on the device that will be able to pull in the upgrade from USB and take control of running it eventually rebooting.  Seems to be an easier route after reading the comments..